# Add Router-outlet returns blank

Tags: angular, angular-material, router

I'm trying to use routing inside mat-drawer but strangely it returns blank page. If I comment out the router-outlet element then it displays the page correctly.
Does anyone know why does it happen?

P.S. if I remove the mat-drawer and put just the router-outlet just after the first line - it works fine

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">

  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened class="sidebar">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

[image]

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {AddUserComponent} from './users/add-user/add-user.component';
import {ViewUserComponent} from './users/view-user/view-user.component';
import {ListUsersComponent} from './users/list-users/list-users.component';
import {DeleteUserComponent} from './users/delete-user/delete-user.component';
import {EditUserComponent} from './users/edit-user/edit-user.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'create', component: AddUserComponent},
  {path: 'view/:id', component: ViewUserComponent},
  {path: 'list', component: ListUsersComponent},
  {path: 'delete/:id', component: DeleteUserComponent},
  {path: 'edit/:id', component: EditUserComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: You will have to show your routing module routes that apply to this outlet

Comment: Now I see that it is related to Angular material. From some reason if I put routler-outlet insdie mat-element it shows blank

Comment: Have you add AppRoutingModule in the import of AppModule ? put   {path: 'list', component: ListUsersComponent} in the first position with  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'list',
  },

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, based on your screenshot, that your current route would match the empty route ''. You should add either a base route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: MyBaseComponent}
  {path: 'create', component: AddUserComponent},
  {path: 'view/:id', component: ViewUserComponent},
  {path: 'list', component: ListUsersComponent},
  {path: 'delete/:id', component: DeleteUserComponent},
  {path: 'edit/:id', component: EditUserComponent}
];
```

or a redirect to another route from the empty route:

```
 {path: 'create', component: AddUserComponent},
  {path: 'view/:id', component: ViewUserComponent},
  {path: 'list', component: ListUsersComponent},
  {path: 'delete/:id', component: DeleteUserComponent},
  {path: 'edit/:id', component: EditUserComponent}
 {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'list',
  },
```

I am assuming you would prefer the 2nd option.

Comment: tried the 2nd option. still shows blank  :-(

Comment: when registering your routes, enable tracing for debugging your app Ex: RouterModule.forRoot(routes,  {enableTracing: true, ....})